# Why cannot I not access my private variables and getter and setter messages in C++

Tags: c++

I have been told over and over again to keep my class variables private because keeping them public would be bad coding practice, so to hit that nail on the head that is what i have been doing from day one. I never had any problems while I had all the code on one page, but now I get an undefined error when I try and use a function to access my private variable.

in my classs.h

```
class classs
{
public:
    classs(void);
    void setAge(int x);
    int getAge();
private:
    int age;
};
```

then in my classs.cpp i have:

```
void setAge(int x)
{
    age = x;
}
```

and

```
int getAge()
{
    return age;
}
```

here it is telling me that age is undefined.  I never had any problems when all of this code was in one .cpp (main.cpp). I have also #include classs.h on my classs.cpp

Comment: I feel I should note that this code would have the exact same problem even if it was all in one file.

Comment: I would also really consider renaming your class from classs with an extra s to something else like Person or even Test.  Adding a letter to a keyword like class is really going to hurt you more than help you.

Comment: We might also wonder what is the need for a setAge function for a Person? I have never set the age of anybody else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening not because your `setAge` definition is in a different file, but because it is now outside the `class classs {}` block.  The compiler doesn't have any way to know that `setAge` is a member of the class, so it doesn't have the class's attributes in scope.

Fix it by declaring your function as `classs::setAge`

Answer (score 4):

You have to properly scope your function definitions using the scope resolution operator, like this:

```
// in person.h
class Person
{
public:
   void set_age(int age);
private:
   int age_;
};

// in your cpp file:
#include "person.h"

void Person::set_age(int age)
{
   age_ = age;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function should be

```
    void classs::setAge(int x)
    {
        age = x;
    }
```

The `classs::` part associates that function definition with the class that declared the function `setAge`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to indicate the scope:

```
void classs::setAge(int x)
{
    age = x;
}

int classs::getAge() 
{ 
    return age; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature is "void classs::setAge(int x)". That means that setAge is a member of classs.

Answer (score 1):

1st of all, for your data encapsulation, I would inline the methods in your header file.

i.e.

```
inline void setAge(int x) { age = x; }
inline int getAge() { return age; }
```

2nd, the code file doesn't know that setAge is a member of your class unless you prefix it with your class name.

i.e.

```
void Person::setAge(int x)
{

 //your code here.
}
```